# Inject same class object in activity and fragment with Dagger 2

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I actually asked a similar question earlier. I just tried to ask in an easy way.

My ActivityBuilder is,

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBuilder {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {MainActivityModule.class, MainFragmentProvider.class})
    abstract MainActivity contributeMainActivity();
}
```

My MainActivity is,

```
class MainActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var injectedString:String
}
```

My Fragment is,

```
class MainFragment : DaggerFragment() {
    /*@Inject
    lateinit var injectedString:String*/
}
```

My ActivityModule is,

```
@Module
public class MainActivityModule {
    @Provides
    static String provideDummyDependency() {
        return "I love Dagger";
    }
}
```

My FragmentModule is,

```
@Module
public class MainFragmentModule {
    /*@Provides
    static String provideDummyDependency() {
        return "I love Dagger";
    }*/
}
```

My FragmentProvider is,

```
@Module
public abstract class MainFragmentProvider {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = MainFragmentModule.class)
    abstract MainFragment provideMainFragmentFactory();
}
```

Now, I can not inject the string both in activity and fragment at the same time. It works one at a time. Is it possible to uncomment the code in FragmentModule and Fragment to inject the same class object in both activity and fragment?

Thanks.

Comment: You can inject it into multiple classes, you just can't provide it in multiple places.  You seem to not understand what a module is-  you do not make 1 module per class you want to inject.  You make 1 module per group of variables you wish to provide

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Does that mean "@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {MainActivityModule.class, MainFragmentProvider.class})" is a group where I can inject in just one place? In that case, can I make another module with just one FragmentModule?

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the same class types using the @Named annotation like 
So in your case something like,

```
@Module
public class MainActivityModule {
    @Provides @Named("activity")
    static String provideActivityString() {
        return "I love Dagger from Activity";
    }
}

@Module
public class MainFragmentModule {
    @Provides @Named("fragment")
    static String provideFragmentString() {
        return "I love Dagger from fragment";
    }
}
```

and when injecting

you can inject as

```
@Inject @Named("activity") String activityString;//Will be "I love Dagger from Activity"

@Inject @Named("fragment") String fragmentString;//Will be "I love Dagger from fragment"
```

you can use any name string, and the above names are for illustration purposes

Look through https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2, have a read it would help you to deal with Dagger 2 and understand more

Edit:
You can provide the same class type within a single module as well, using the @Named annotation

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I was trying to do is, I will have one factory builder for viewmodel. So if I want to inject the factory in both fragmnt and activity what do I have to do? If you have some time look at the FeedbackActivity in this repo. https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvvm-architecture